# Andrea Bocelli Aspiration

Tags: phonology, phonetics, spanish, italian, aspiration

I have been listen to Andrea Bocelli's songs lately. A noticeable feature of his pronunciation while singing Spanish songs is that he constantly pronounces the plosives (especially at word-initial positions) with a puff of air.

This is peculiar since in his native language, Italian, aspiration does not contrast and most of the time the plosives, namely p, t, and k are realized unaspirated. So I'm quite curious why would he alter the pronunciation if the phonology of the two languages are similar enough.

Comment: I suspect that this has to do not with contrastive phonologies of Italian and Spanish, but with vocal technique. But perhaps someone has a better suggestion.

Comment: Can you put a link to a specific part of a song where you are hearing aspirated stops? Maybe it has to do with signing vs. speaking.